# getting AccessViolationException in IOCompletionCallback

Tags: c#, sockets, io-completion-ports

I get the following exception on application startup:

```
System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Threading.Overlapped.get_iocbHelper()
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

That's the entire call stack. It only happens one in twenty runs right on application startup. I do use IOCompletion in my socket code. I assume it is related to that. However, why would this exception not show when I call `Socket.ReceiveFromAsync`? I have a lot of sockets that simultaneously call `ReceiveFromAsync`, but I don't call it twice on the same socket concurrently. Any ideas on the cause?

Comment: here's a start.. post the relevant code call stack means nothing at this point if we can't see what's calling and or making the specific call are you using and `Tasks()` also based on this line `at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)` I can just about guess that this is a `POINTER` issue

Comment: what version of .net framework is this project in..`2.0, 3.5, 4.0..`??

Comment: This is .NET 4.5.0 with VS2012. I don't know that this error occurs without the debugger attached, but I somewhat doubt it.

Comment: This code runs on the completion of the transfer, just before your Completed event handler is called.  This is an environmental problem, you need to get your machine stable again.  Start with usual list of crapware that wants to get involved with networking, anti-malware, firewall at the top of that list.

Answer (score 0):

After trying really hard to get the IO-completion method to work, I finally gave up and just wrote my own threads that call the synchronous versions of send and receive.  I haven't had any problems since.

I have some C++ code that uses IO-completion, in a high-volume setting even, and I've never had this problem.

So it seems clear to me that the C# implementation of IO-completion is bugged, and that it's not anti-malware, firewall, or any (non-Microsoft) crapware.

Comment: This is just your suggestion without any proof. I doubt that Microsoft code is so badly written that you are the first to find this "bug". It is far more probable that there is a severe bug in your code.

Comment: @Elmue: The affected code comes down to creating an AsyncCallback and passing it to BeginSend(), which leads to a call to EndSend(), vs. calling Send() from a message-loop thread. There's not really much room for a "severe bug in my code".

Comment: Well that is where your exception is thrown. But the CAUSE of the error may be another place in your code which PROVOKES the exception later. So if you don't post a code which can be used to reproduce this problem you will never get an answer on Stackoverflow. I'am using BeginSend() and EndSend() a lot in my code without problem. So it has something to do with your code, which we don't know.